# How to identify a button click in coded UI Customised code

Tags: coded-ui-tests

In UIMAP.CS file in both the Recorded method and assertion method, I am not able to identify the button click.

Is there any way I can get hold of the button click event?

I am able to get hold the button in to a UITESTCONTROL variable but the options I was able to see are "exists", "enabled","name" etc...

I tried checking it with assertions too when I dragged the cross hair on to the clicked button , assertions are generated only for checking the existence,correctness of text and name but not the events occured on it..

Please help in this regard..

Comment: does anything happen when you click that button? can you check if another control exists on that event?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the Control/Object on which you want to use the Click operation is a button and not any Web Element or control which does not support the Click operation.

Once verified, you can do the following:

Record a New Session and while recording click on that button, stop your recording.

Open the UIMap.cs and navigate to that button control.  The intellitrace would show you all the available options for that control.

Thanks
Nikhil